# Why I can't connect to MySQL Driver database in java?

Tags: java, mysql-connector

Hello my connection code works in other class but in here says:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find the driver in the classpath!

my code is following:

```
tfield2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                    if(tfield2.getText().equals("REC1U")) {

                        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/redpraire";
                        String username = "username";
                        String password = "password";

                        System.out.println("Connecting database...");

                        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
                            System.out.println("Database connected!");
                            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                            try {
                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");

                                while(rs.next()) {
                                  // some code here
                                }

                                rs.next();

                            } finally {
                                stmt.close();
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", ex);
                        }

                        System.out.println("Loading driver...");

                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", ex);
                        }

                    } else {

                    }





                } else if(e.getKeyCode() == 121) {
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();
                    new QueryMenu();
                }
            }
        });
```

i have tried different ways to change it but nothing will work... in separate class this connection works perfectly fine...
i am just out of ideas. any help?

Comment: You need to have the JAR in your classpath.  The error seems clear.  You should close your ResultSet, too.  Empty else block?  Bad idea.

Comment: right! i have had it imported into different project now it all works perfectly thanks @duffymo ! but the empty else block is because it was not necessary to copy here as it takes less space without ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try running it as follows:

```
java -cp path-to-jdbc-driver-jar your-java-class
```

e.g.

```
java -cp hsqldb-2.2.9.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
```

I hope, you are already aware of `-classpath` or `-cp` option. If not, go through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

do you install `MySQL jdbc` driver
Verify you your data data base connection to

`Database -> new connection -> test connection`